# Pyspark loop over dataframe and decrement column value

Tags: loops, pyspark

I need help with looping row by row in pyspark dataframe:

E.g:

```
df1
+---------+
|id|value|
+---------+
|a|100|
|b|100|
|c|100|
+---------+
```

I need to loop and decrease the value based on another dataframe

```
df2 

+---------+---------------
|id|value|timestamp
+---------+---------------
|a|20    |2020-01-02 01:30
|a|50    |2020-01-02 05:30
|b|50    |2020-01-15 07:30
|b|80    |2020-02-01 09:30
|c|50    |2020-02-01 09:30
+---------+-------------
```

Expected Output based on a udf or function

customFunction(df1(row_n)))

```
 df1
+---------+
|id|value|
+---------+
|a|30| ( 100-20 ) ( 80 - 50 )
|b|50| ( 100-50 ) skip operation since lhs < rhs ( 50 - 80 )
|c|50| ( 100 - 50 ) 
+---------+
```

How do i achieve this in pyspark ? Also the dataframes will have > 50k rows

Comment: shouldn't a left join and some aggregation help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with joining both the dataframes & using [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) to aggregate the values from `df2` to determine if the `value` is greater or less than the aggregation.

## Combining DataFrames

```
input_str1 = """
|a|100
|b|100
|c|100
""".split("|")

input_values1 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str1))[1:]

input_list1 = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(input_values1[0::2],input_values1[1::2])]

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list1,['id','value'])

input_str2 = """
|a|20    |2020-01-02 01:30
|a|50    |2020-01-02 05:30
|b|50    |2020-01-15 07:30
|b|80    |2020-02-01 09:30
|c|50    |2020-02-01 09:30
""".split("|")

input_values2 = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str2))[1:]

input_list2 = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(input_values2[0::3]
,input_values2[1::3],input_values2[2::3])]

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list2,['id','value','timestamp'])

finalDF = (sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                        ,sparkDF1['id'] == sparkDF2['id']
                        ,'inner'
                       ).select(sparkDF1["*"],sparkDF2['value'].alias('value_right')))

finalDF.show()

+---+-----+-----------+
| id|value|value_right|
+---+-----+-----------+
|  c|  100|         50|
|  b|  100|         50|
|  b|  100|         80|
|  a|  100|         20|
|  a|  100|         50|
+---+-----+-----------+
```

## GroupBy

```
agg_lst = [
            F.first(F.col('value')).alias('value')
           ,F.sum(F.col('value_right')).alias('sum_value_right')
           ,F.min(F.col('value_right')).alias('min_value_right')
         ]
finalDF = finalDF.groupBy('id').agg(*agg_lst).orderBy('id')


finalDF = finalDF.withColumn('final_value'
                             ,F.when(F.col('value') > F.col('sum_value_right')
                                 ,F.col('value') - F.col('sum_value_right'))\
                             .otherwise(F.col('value') - F.col('min_value_right'))
                            )

finalDF.show()

+---+-----+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| id|value|sum_value_right|min_value_right|final_value|
+---+-----+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|  a|  100|           70.0|             20|       30.0|
|  b|  100|          130.0|             50|       50.0|
|  c|  100|           50.0|             50|       50.0|
+---+-----+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

**Note - If the above logic does not work on your entire set , implementing a UDF with your custom logic , along with groupBy would be the ideal solution**